# Making a custom help center page

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, pages, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I am working now on a new WordPress theme and I want to make a help center system to allow users that will buy my theme do add helper articles.

So my plan is:

1- Make a normal new page and create the page-help.php file.

2- Create two post types first named sections and the second article.

3- Add the sections posts and articles inside the page-help file.

The problem now that I don't need the link of sections and articles be directly like this:

```
http://localhost/section/using-wordpres/
http://localhost/article/how-to-use-the-wordpres/
```

I want to make a rewrite rule to add help beside the section and article post type to be the final link like that:

```
http://localhost/help/section/using-wordpres/
http://localhost/help/article/how-to-use-the-wordpres/
```

Really this is very important for me and I hope anyone helps me to make this or at least something like that I want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can control those values with the `slug` argument when you register your post types, you don't need to add any additional rewrite rules.

Comment: @Milo Really thank you for your reply please continue with me, Did you mean something like this? rewrite' => array('slug' => 'help')? this will change the name of post type to something else will not like I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this when you register your post types. The `slug` can be a path:

```
$section_args = array(
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'help/section' ),
    // your other args...
);

$article_args = array(
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'help/article' ),
    // your other args...
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much I never thought that I can make it like this :)